# How to fix "ssh permission denied please try again error" in git configuration on Windows

Tags: windows, git, openssh, git-server

I am trying to configure git server and client on two local windows machines. I installed git software on both the machines. Enabled openssh server optional feature on the server and created a bare repository on the server. Then tried to clone the server's bare repository on the client, it asked me the password of the server's user but, even after I entered the right password it was giving the below error message.

Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

I have tried to figure out the cause for the error. After browsing for this error on google I got to know that it is ssh not configured properly. One suggestion I found was to check if ssh working properly without git involvement using the command

ssh -Tv ram-pc1@10.208.27.100, it also failed by giving below error message:

$ ssh -Tv ram-pc1@10.208.27.100

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.208.27.100 [10.208.27.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.208.27.100:22 as 'ram-pc1'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:27NSp0TODhiZ68zbYLvsaqPNMp8tE0ZanMeoeQp+u14
debug1: Host '10.208.27.100' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:2KyRU6bbWWkN+IBYN6xiuWQuHl0pKL6Cim6K4/6RBek /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ram-pc1@10.208.27.100's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
ram-pc1@10.208.27.100's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
ram-pc1@10.208.27.100's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ram-pc1@10.208.27.100: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Below is my ssh_config file settings:

```
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

I have spent a lot of time to resolve this error. But not succeeded. Please help in solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi please put your sshd_config  file as well.
check PasswordAuthentication property in that if it was set to "no" please change it to "yes" and restart your ssh service by  "sudo service ssh restart" command.

Comment: I have update my question with my config file details pls check once

Comment: My PasswordAuthentication is already set to yes :(

Comment: Instead of debugging this instance, you can also try to do the setup in a fresh way.
If you like I suggest you follow: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-Win32_OpenSSH , you can also follow this for generating the ssh key pair: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/ sometime it is better to redo instead of fixing a tooling bug that occurs because we miss/skip something.

Comment: maybe relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/1362298/permission-denied-publickey-password-keyboard-interactive-error also https://serverfault.com/questions/598058/ssh-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-with-mic-password

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of ~ram-pc1/.ssh/authorized_keys on the 10.208.27.100 server side: it should include your public key.

Said public key should be an rsa one (without passphrase for now) named `C:\Users\Admin\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` (and id_rsa for the private) key, generated with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""`